# Split dataframe when value in first column is not NA

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have imported a data set looking like this from excel to r-studio

```
Station Indicator Resp Status
   1        Ca      +      16 
   1        Zn      -      134
   1        Pb      +      3.5
   2        Ca      +      4.6
   3        Zn      -      156
```

==========

I would like to split the dataframe in a way, that when "station" is not NA it would make a  new dataframe with the name of the station fx "1". 
In that way I would have a dataframe for each of my stations.

```
station 1:
  Ca      +      16 
  Zn      -      134
  Pb      +      3.5

station 2:
  Ca      +      4.6

station 3: 
  Zn      -      156
```

I have tried the split function

```
df1=split(df,station=!"NA"])
```

But it does not work for me

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This however removes the 2 observations at station 1 with indicator Zn and Pb.

Comment: Did this help? I have now given every row a station name. So now there is no NA's but instead different station names

Comment: Try `split(df1[-1], df1$Station)`.  To name the list element, `setNames(split(df1[-1], df1$Station), paste0('Station', unique(df1$Station)))`

Comment: Thank you - that works! Do you know if I can call each of dataset representing a station something, so I can work with it separately?

Comment: It is better to work within the list itself rather than having separate objects in the global environment.  But, if you really need to have, after naming the list elements. `list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could `split` the dataset ('df1') with the first column i.e. `Station`

```
 lst <- split(df1[-1], df1$Station)
 names(lst) <- paste0('Station', names(lst))
```

If we need separate objects in the global environment (not reccommended)

```
 list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)

 Station1
 #   Indicator Resp Status
 #1        Ca    +   16.0
 #2        Zn    -  134.0
 #3        Pb    +    3.5
```