# Repeating ifelse statement on row in dataframe or using ifelse-statement on a vector with multible factors

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, vector

Hope someone can help with this problem in R.

I'm having a dataset (df) that in a bit simplified looks like this

```
 Resp Status    Threshold
  1      16        3
  0      134       4
  1      3.5       3
```

I would like to perform this ifelse-test on each of the rows

```
CR.Wat = ifelse(Threshold != "NA" && Status != "NA", 
                ifelse(Resp != 1, Threshold/Status, Status/Threshold), 
                "")
```

I expect to get three values of Threshold/Status. But instead I get only one value.

I assume I should somehow tell the that I would like it for each of the rows.

I tried to do this by using this formula

```
CR.Wat = ifelse(c(Threshold) != "NA" && c(Status) != "NA",
                ifelse(c(Resp) != 1, c(Threshold/Status), c(Status/Threshold)), 
                "")
```

But this did not affect anything.

Comment: Use only a single `&` i.e. `with(df, ifelse(Treshold!="NA" & Status!="NA",ifelse(Resp!=1,Treshold/Status,Status/Treshold),""))`  Also, BTW, for checking NA, it is `is.na(Status)`.  I assume you have 'character' NAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operation only returned one value because you used `&&` instead of `&`. You can read about the difference between these two operators at `?"&"`.

That being said, your operation can be done without the use of a nested ifelse by noticing that you want Threshold/Status (aka `(Threshold/Status)^1`) when Resp != 1 and Status/Threshold (aka `(Threshold/Status)^(-1)`) when Resp == 1.

```
with(dat, (Treshold / Status)^(1-2*(Resp == 1)))
# [1] 5.33333333 0.02985075 1.16666667
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked perfectly! Do you have a link to a site where I can read about the "with"-thing? Cause even though it works I do not have a clue, how it works

Comment: Do you also have a solution for this problem? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401206/split-dataframe-when-value-in-first-column-is-not-na

Comment: @EmilieK Basically it means you don't need to keep typing `dat$var` to access variable `var` from data frame `dat`. You could have already written the expression as `(dat$Treshold / dat$Status)^(1-2*(dat$Resp == 1))`.